# Taxonomy of understanding: term

Tags: terminology

Years ago I encountered a term to describe the way verbs are used taxonomically in college syllabi to suggest different levels of comprehension. The hierarchy, in order of increasing sophistication of understanding, was something like:

- identify
- describe
- demonstrate
- master

There were other terms, which I've forgotten. This hierarchy was named, if I remember, after the person who established it, but I can't remember the name. I've tried searching, to no avail. Does anyone know the name of this system?

Comment: I don't think this is a writing question, so I'm voting to close. But my guess is that you are talking about Bloom's Taxonomy. There's a terrific book by Anderson and Krathwohl that refines the model.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about writing. It might fit better in Academia or some other Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Yes, Bloom's taxonomy is it! Sorry the question was off topic, but thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want Bloom's.

It can be considered on-topic as a writing framework, a method for organizing a paper. For example, if OP was tasked with critiquing a learning program where s/he is consulting, s/he would use Bloom's Taxonomy to argue whether lessons presented are sequenced correctly.

Same example, but focusing on learner assessment. If OP needs to evaluate and report against an assessment, their response may be the questions are not sequenced correctly, meaning difficult questions are asked too early.

Sequencing questions in order of easier to most difficult allows us to see at what point the student's knowledge stops. We have identified a gap.

Without Bloom's, OP could not write a credible report. It would be only their opinion.